# Most optimized way for creating objects from a huge set of objects

Tags: python, object, iterator, generator

I have an iterator (`userEnvironments`) that contains a lot of user environment objects which I want for creating a dictionary containing `environment.name` as the key and a new `EnvironmentStore` object that would use `environment`.

```
for environment in userEnvironments:
       set_cache(user,environment)

def set_cache(user, environment):
       _environments_cache[environment.name] = EnvironmentStore(user, environment)
```

The memory efficiency is not important here but creating all of these objects will take approximately 4 seconds.

So the question is, what would be a good approach in python that could create the objects only on-demand (as in, creates the objects when another method wants to call the class) similar to a generator?

Comment: What is taking the time here, creating `EnvironmentStore` or iterating over `userEnvironments`? You cannot 'generate' key lookups over a generator, but you *can* postpone creating a `EnvironmentStore` if you only stored the original `environment` object.

Comment: @Martijn's suggestion is what came to my mind, too; create a custom dictionary (e.g. `MutableMapping` subclass) that stores the `environment` on set, but builds the `EnvironmentStore` with it only on get (you can cache the latter, so it only gets built once).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Creating `EnvironmentStore` takes more time because of its structure. Therefore I want to change my code so as to create `EnvironmentStore` on-demand rather than all at once.

Comment: @Omid yes, that's exactly what Martijn and I are suggesting. You can't access the iterator by key *"on-demand"*, but you can postpone creating an `EnvironmentStore` from the `environment`.

Comment: have you considered to make a custom lazy dictionary which builds itself when you deman a value by key by overrriding __getitem__ method?

Comment: @jonrsharpe what do you mean by postpone turning the environment into an `EnvironmentStore`. Can you elaborate on it please. How would that help?

Comment: @Omid I mean store the `environment` in the dictionary, rather than the `EnvironmentStore`, then only create the latter when you *access* the dictionary. Martijn has already posted one implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If creating the `EnvironmentStore()` instances is the time sink here you can postpone creating these by using a custom mapping:

```
from collections import Mapping

class EnvironmentStoreMapping(Mapping):
    def __init__(self, user, environments):
        self._user = user
        self._envs = {env.name: env for env in environments}
        self._cache = {}

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            return self._cache[key]
        except KeyError:
            store = EnvironmentStore(self._user, self._envs[key])
            self._cache[key] = store
            return store

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._envs)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._envs)

    def __contains__(self, key):
        return key in self._envs

_environments_cache = EnvironmentStoreMapping(user, userEnvironments)
```

Now creation of the `EnvironmentStore` is postponed until it is actually looked up. If not all `env.name` values are ever looked up, this will not only postpone the cost, but avoid it altogether for those keys never used.

Comment: Thanks. This is so close to what I was looking for.